# Unexpected token -

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error

I have below working fine:

```
var varName= {
    variable_one: 'short_name',
    variable_two: 'long_name',
    variable_three: 'long_name',
    variable_four: 'short_name',
    variable_five: 'long_name',
    variable_six: 'short_name'
};
```

but if i change into:

```
var varName= {
    variable-one: 'short_name',
    variable-two: 'long_name',
    variable-three: 'long_name',
    variable-four: 'short_name',
    variable-five: 'long_name',
    variable-six: 'short_name'
};
```

it show me error:

> Unexpected token -

then the question is: how do it escape the '-' because i need the name with '-' instead of '_'

i tried to put ''' or '"' but didn't work T_T

Thanks

Comment: Put the property names in quotes.

Comment: Quote: `"variable-one": "value",`

Comment: @Pointy What use would that be if the properties are not normally accessible with those names?

Comment: @PaulStelian - They are normally accessible with those names, just not via dot notation. Square bracket notation still works.

Comment: @Quentin ...That's one reason I don't like JS... Deleted my answer.

Comment: var varName= {
    "variable-one": "short_name",
    "variable-two": "long_name",
   "variable-three": "long_name"
    
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
let varName= {
    'variable-one': 'short_name',
    'variable-two': 'long_name',
    'variable-three': 'long_name',
    'variable-four': 'short_name',
    'variable-five': 'long_name',
    'variable-six': 'short_name'
};
```

JavaScript takes the - as a literal minus sign.

Answer (score 4):

`-` is the [subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2), you can't use it in an identifier. Use a string (with quote marks around it) for the property name instead. ([Object literal syntax](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) accepts strings or identifiers for property names).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript tries to interpret the `-` as a minus. You should simply be able to put the names into quotes too:

```
var varName= {
    'variable-one': 'short_name',
    'variable-two': 'long_name',
    'variable-three': 'long_name',
    'variable-four': 'short_name',
    'variable-five': 'long_name',
    'variable-six': 'short_name'
};
```